# Embedding VTK output in wxpanel with C++

Tags: python, c++, wxwidgets, vtk

I am a C++ beginner and looking for a working example which embeds VTK output in wxpanel with C++ language. I came across the following 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxvtk/
which was last updated four years ago, and doesn't compile with the latest cmake, VTK and WxWidgets. I am using MinGW-W64 compiler on windows 10. I see that the same can be easily done using python which must be using some C++/C code internally.

Comment: how many errors do you have? If you don't know how to fix them - can you post them? Maybe someone can help with figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally modified the original source-code of [**wxvtk**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxvtk/) and **CMakeLists.txt** in order to make it work with **WxWidgets-3.0.3** and **VTK-8**. Modifications were required since a lot has changed in VTK source code during last five years or so. The modified version with updated source code is available [here](https://github.com/harshn05/wxvtk-UpdatedOnJan23_2018). It builds **wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor.(dll,lib)** as well as compiles a minimal working example (SAMPLE.cpp) with dynamic linking to the wxVTKRenderWindowInteractor.dll leading to MAIN.exe. A screenshot of the output window (MAIN.exe) is shown below:

[image]

I hope it will be helpful for the community.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code.  IMHO a zip file in your dropbox is not a good way to share code.  I would reccomend using a public GitHub repository, or any similar open source hosting platform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_source_code_hosting_facilities

Comment: Hi @ravenspoint , as per your suggestion I have created a public GitHub repo and included/updated in my post. Thanks